# I am trying to load the txt file but it's giving following error:Out of Memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code:

```
from pandas import read_csv

ds = read_csv('hpc.txt', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]}, index_col=['datetime'])
print(ds.shape)
print(ds.head())
```

Snapshot of *hpc.txt*:

[image]

the code is meant to output the shape of the file but it isn't.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you shared a part of `hpc.txt`

Comment: Hi Fozoro,I have added a snapshot of txt file.

Comment: How big is hpc.txt? And can you show the headers?

Comment: around 120 MB@Matthias Fripp

Comment: Date;Time;Global_active_power;Global_reactive_power;Voltage;Global_intensity;Sub_metering_1;Sub_metering_2;Sub_metering_3 
-headers (9 parameters)

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Comment: @MatthiasFripp any answer or guesses.

Comment: 120 MB is pretty large, but I'm surprised it's running out of memory. You could try setting `low_memory=True` or leave it unspecified. It may also help to provide an explicit date format for parsing (same as used by strftime). Also, there's no column called `datetime`, so I'm not sure how it's handling your index specification. If all you want is the shape of the table, there are other ways to get that. But you actually need to get the data into a dataframe, right?